# Python File I/O:How to know if text exist on a line and go to the next line

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, io

In python file io I get just frustrated because, when I try to write to the next line it just doesnt seem to work.

Ive tried "\n" but It just erases the existing text in the file

```
fo = open("acckeys.txt","w+")
fo.write(psw+"_"+usr+"\n")
```

So how would I check if text already exists in a line and write to the next line without erasing the existing text?

Comment: You are using the `w` flag when you open the file. This writes whatever you want to the file, erasing the original contents. [As chris points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27263024/198633), using the `a` flag appends whatever you write to the file, **after** the pre-existing contents of the file

Comment: Thanks!! I appriciate your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the file with the append flag, it will write to the next free line.

```
fo = open("file.txt", "a")
```

Note you can also open with "a+" to allow reading as well.

**"a+":**
Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the statement

```
fo = open("acckeys.txt")
```

It will open the acckeys.txt file in a read mode, I assume this file already exists, Otherwise It will throw IOError with the error message "No such file or directory: 'acckeys.txt'"

And This line will write to the file from the pointer it is currently pointing to. You can find out the current pointer using seek() of file handle, (fo in this case). Usually current offset pointer is the starting of file.

```
fo.write(psw+"_"+usr+"\n")
```

Now your question 
So how would I check if text already exists in a line and write to the next line without erasing the existing text?

In order to check if the text exist in the file, you can read the file using

```
fileContent = fo.read()
```

And then check for the length of fileContent.

If you open a file in an append mode like this

```
fo = open("acckeys.txt" ,"a")
```

then irrespective of the file content or non-existent of the file itself. It will create a file incase of non-existent or set the offset pointer to the last line.